# How to remove index from module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Eg : http://www.example.com/module/index/index

In Magento 1 we can do in etc/config.xml like

```
...
    <rewrite>
       <store_url>
            <from><![CDATA[/module\/(.*)/]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[module/index/index/id/$1/]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
        </store_url>
    </rewrite>
  ...
```

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: I need to change route